# How can I get HTML element value inside Angular JS conroller while the page is getting loaded

Tags: ajax, json, angularjs, struts2

Let me tel the scenario where I am stuck, I will try to explain simply rather than telling the actual.

1st : I am on page 1. Where few subjects are there with unique names.
2nd : I will click on one subject, which will call an struts2 action (lets call it ActionA)at back end with the unique subject name as a request parameter(Request type = GET).
3rd : Action A will only redirect to "Tutorial page".
4th : While loading it will make an AJAX call to another Struts2 action (lets call it ActionB), which will return JSON containing tutorials for that Subject.

**Problem:** As I am calling ActionA first and passing the subject name which is just redirecting the page to some other page. On page load I am calling another action to get the JSON. I am not able to get the request parameter value at ActionB that is the one which is returning JSON.

**Note:** I am using Struts2-JSON plugin thats why not need two actions, one for redirecting the page another for getting the JSON at page load.

Solution tried: I have tried to get the request parameter value that is the Subject name, putting a hidden field in the Tutorial page. But unable to get the value from inside the Angular JS controller.

Comment: Are you using any router? ngRoute/uiRouter?

Comment: No I am new to angular JS, can this ngRoute help me in this situation??

Comment: I am not familiar with struts, therefore I am not understanding the scenario correctly. Do you render your html on the backend? Normally you switch pages with ngRoute/uiRouter and these modules have a 'resolve' method where you can load any data the page needs before rendering.

Comment: Oh I misread your problem, if the problem is that you don't have the request parameter for ActionB because you already loaded a new page, try using a service where you store all the variables you need in multiple places and Inject this service in your controllers. If that's what you need let me know and I will add example code.

Comment: Ya this is sounding good, I i can get something which be available across the pages then my problem can be solved, It would be great if u can give some example.

Comment: At the same time, I would like to clarify my problem once again, in my case the page is being changed that is another page is getting loaded thus all the js files will be loaded again. I am not sure whether i can store something globally. If there is some way it would be great for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example for a shared Service: [http://plnkr.co/edit/P2ItVj20RYCJVjdIaXfY](http://plnkr.co/edit/P2ItVj20RYCJVjdIaXfY?p=preview)

But you are right if you reload the page this doesn't work. I think your scenario needs tweaking if you want to use angular or any other single page framework for that matter. One purpose of single page applications is to minimize reloads, preferable none. If your action A only returns a template where you then want to input the result of action B, I recommend looking at [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07) or [uiRouter](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), where you define a template (result of action A) and a controller for that view. This template than replaces a section of your page (ng-view) with the new template. If both are new to you I would recommend looking at [uiRouter](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), it is similar but it gives you a lot more possibilities. Both provide a "resolve" function where you can load your action B before the page is rendered.

**Code from plunker**

```
angular.module("app", [])
.controller("MainController", ['SharedService', function(SharedService) {
  var vm = this;
  //bind to service
  vm.service = SharedService;


}]);
```

**Service**

```
angular.module("app")
.factory("SharedService", [function() {
  var service = {
    id: "test"
  }

  return service;
}]);
```